# Uncaught TypeError: this.rules[this.name] is not a function in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2

After I updated my magento from 2.3 to 2.3.2, I am getting a console error like:

This error only appears after I log in to my admin panel and open Configurations settings from the Store tab. Due to this error, I am unable to change any settings in the configuration.

I have already tried fixing the JS with some changes but nothing helped so far.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.rules[this.name] is not a function
    at UiClass.apply (rule.min.js:1)
    at solutions.min.js:1
    at Function._.each._.forEach (underscore.min.js:7)
    at applicationRules (solutions.min.js:1)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (underscore.min.js:7)
    at UiClass.initSolutions (solutions.min.js:1)
    at UiClass.initialize (solutions.min.js:1)
    at new UiClass (class.min.js:3)
    at (index):2142
    at Object.execCb (baf602f715535fc4d36d131159d94e25.min.js:112)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue as you, cleared the magento cache

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Then cleared the browser cache. Pressed CTRL+F5 (windows) to reload the page and the error went away. I'm assuming this happened because I was logged in to magento admin v2.3 prior to upgrading. Would be great to know if this was indeed the case though.

Answer (score 0):

I was using cloudfront for CDN of static files, which was the reason of this issue occurred. I removed the CDN and it started to work. I figured due to using CDN all the static files were not getting synced on cloudfront.